# A closed path on the Rubik's cube

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics, rubiks-cube, graph-theory

Is it possible to draw a closed path on the surface of a standard $3\times3\times3$ Rubik's cube

- such that the path traverses each of the $54$ little squares exactly once, and
- such that the path does *not* go through any corner of these little squares?

Comment: By "not go through any corner" do you mean non-diagonal?

Comment: Reminds me of the "Attach 3 houses to 3 wells without crossing pipes" puzzle

Answer (score 14, accepted):

An observation is..

> that you can traverse a cube's face from one corner and end up diagonally opposite or in same column (or row).
>
>  [image]

Using this observation, one of many possible solutions is (left image is front of cube, right image is inside view):

> [image]

Comment: very nice, what did you use to make these drawings?

Comment: @Jonah: I used Microsoft Powerpoint.  It has a draw button for cube and path (in red), but for the 3x3 grid I drew individual lines.

Answer (score 12):

The minimum degree of the graph involved is 4: each of the 56 squares has exactly four neighbors. [Thus, the graph is 4-connected](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/690822/show-that-g-is-k-connected).

It is also planar: we can obviously draw it on a sphere (imagine a "deformed" Rubik's cube.)

[Thus it is Hamiltonian](http://people.math.gatech.edu/~thomas/PAP/ham.pdf).

Comment: Another argument that it's planar is that it can clearly be drawn on a sphere, which is equivalent to being planar.

Comment: That's a very elegant argument, @xnor. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

The answer is

> Yes:

As can be seen:

> [image]
>  (Similar path on opposite three faces)

Answer (score 4):

There are actually sticker mods that does exactly what you describe, called **Maze Cubes**, and they are pretty hard to solve. There are a lot of different lay-outs for Maze Cubes. Here is a potential path - the original one from 1982 (available for sale at [OliverStickers.com](http://oliverstickers.com/maze-cube.html?filter_name=maze)):

> [image]
>
>
>  [image][image]

[Here is some more info in the TwistyPuzzles Museum.](http://twistypuzzles.com/cgi-bin/puzzle.cgi?pkey=933)

Answer (score 3):

> Yes, you can
>
>  On the base, draw an S shaped path going from near-left to far-right
>  On the right and front faces, do an S shape so you end up on the front face, top left.
>  On the top, draw an S shape, going from front-left to back-right
>  On the left and back, do an S shape, so you end up on the left face, bottom-near.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. Each and every square in the Rubik's cube has four non-diagonal neighbors, including those neighbors on adjacent faces. There are no squares with an odd number of neighbors, so the parity checks out, and a closed path can be drawn.

I have just sketched out a couple of these paths. If requested, I can attach.

Comment: The argument you are thinking only works for [Eulerian cycles](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerianCycle.html), while this problem is asking for a [Hamiltonian cycle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HamiltonianCycle.html). The former uses every edge once, the latter must use every vertex once.

Comment: @Sleafar: The edge squares of a 3x3 square have three neighbors each, not an even number.

Comment: @ard Right, my fault. But can you please provide an example?